# Setting a listener on bitmap in a canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, ontouchlistener

I have a view in which I have placed a canvas and on that canvas I draw a few bitmaps dynamically (based on some calculation). The user needs to be able to touch a bitmap and get a response (ie. a dialog should appear). I understand that bitmap is a representation of an image and that it cannot hold a listener on its own. 
Is there a smarter way of doing this other than placing a listener on the entire view (which fills the whole screen) and then checking if the coordinates of the touch event match the area covered any of my small and scattered bitmaps?

Comment: no, you have to check the coordinates of the touch event, is it that hard to call `Rect.contains(int x, int y)` ?

Comment: well, one solution is to use separate views for every bitmap you draw. This way you can set individual listeners for each view and can easily identify the bitmap which has been clicked.

Comment: @pskink I just think it would be more effective (hence "smarter") to have listeners attached to images rather than running through a list or rectangles each time the user touches the screen.

Comment: @Vikalp How can I then place these views within the canvas? I though the view holds the canvas, not the other way around.

Comment: so add the custom "listener" class, inside it you will still have to iterate over a list of rectangles, there is no magic...

Comment: @panonski you will need to make your own custom view class which will extend 'View' class. And in onDraw() method of your custom class, you can draw anything over canvas .

Comment: @Vikalp I already have a custom class which extends View and I am drawing paths and bitmaps in my onDraw(). However, I believe a View cannot be "drawn" over a canvas. If you have an example for drawing "anything" over canvas, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I will write this so that the question doesn't stay unanswered. The answer is "No." You have to do it the hard way, mentioned above.